# Modeling a Game character

Tags: modeling, sculpt

Im new to Blender, and want to try out making a game character.

My question is, is scultping easier to do? And when I sculpt a model, do I HAVE to do the retopology after to make it animated, or is that just something some people prefer to do?

Thanks! :)

Comment: It's up to you how you create your character, modeling and sculpting are different tools for different goals. If you are looking into animating this for a game what matters is having efficient topology, both in terms of edge flow and in vertex count.

Comment: Sculpting is often used for giving the mesh different details, starting from basic shape and silhoutte and up to small cracks, lines etc. To do that you need high polycount in order sculpting to work (as it needs geometry). Game needs lowpoly model. So likely yes, you need to do retopology on the sculpted model. Though your question is too broad for this site so far (e.g. sculpting could be used like Proportional edit etc, hence it's better to tell you need retopo for high poly object), for discussions like this try https://blenderartists.org/